# Is this a valid html5 markup approach?

Tags: css, html

I am designing a video site and just wanna ask some suggestions, ideas and improvements of my current html5 base layout.

I read a lot of articles from google but it's confusing. I need some straightforward suggestions.
I am new to css so please be gentle :)

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/willrpx/g0s6r9ep/)

```css
body {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  font: normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #777;
  overflow-x: hidden
}
a {
  color: #888;
}
a:active {
  color: #444;
}
header .wrap,
nav,
.contentwrapper,
footer .wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
header,
nav,
section,
aside .wrap,
footer {
  background: #333;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222
}
section {
  border: 1px solid #222
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
main {
  float: right;
  width: 820px;
}
aside {
  float: left;
  width: 170px
}
footer {
  line-height: 30px;
}
footer ul {
  font-size: 14px;
}
footer li {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
footer li.cr {
  float: left
}
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Site title</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" href="#">menu1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" href="#">menu2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="contentwrapper group">
  <main>
    <section>
      <div class="head">
        <h1>Featured Videos</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Latest Videos</h1>
    </section>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <div class="wrap">
      category list here
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      ads here
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="wrap group">
    <ul>
      <li class="cr">website.com &copy; 2014</li>
      <li><a href="./contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="./rss.xml">Rss</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="./sitemap.xml">Sitemap</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Webmaster$</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Try [validator.nu](http://validator.nu/) to validate the html code and [csslint.net](http://csslint.net/) to validate css code.

Comment: sorry if it appears off topic to you. I do not have a pro knowledge about css, I just learn the basics by myself and of course from google. I am not sure about the proper use of the semantics I am using though I read their descriptions already. Also it's a little bit hard to understand too coz english is not my first language :P Thanks for the validator link.

Comment: Don't be sorry.. I vote to close after giving the answer in above comment. no offence. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

All of your syntax is valid, and your CSS looks fine. Just be sure to keep you code clean and simple throughout your project, so that you don't have 50 stylesheets for who-knows-what (speaking from experience XD).

Best of luck to your project.

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

From the HTML5 spec :: [`DIV`](http://drafts.htmlwg.org/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)

> Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element of last resort, for when no other element is suitable. Use of more appropriate elements instead of the div element leads to better accessibility for readers and easier maintainability for authors.

You should not use `DIV` elements where there are not necessary, especially `<div class="wrap">` inside `HEADER`, `<div class="contentwrapper group">` as parent of `MAIN`, and `<div class="wrap group">` inside bottom `FOOTER` from your code, are redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I added wrap because I read that it's not valid to add class on semantics. Maybe I could just use .group and remove the .wrap. I use group to clear floats as well. Can you show me your improved version? thanks

Comment: Where you red not to add `class` on semantics? [`class`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes) is [global attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#global-attributes) and can be used on any element.